# How to prevent popup blocker in facebook connect for web sites?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a facebook login app for my site. But pop-up blocker blocks it. I searched in google it says to add a onclick option and I have one. But still it's not working. I have posted my code below

js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 window.fbAsyncInitialize = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '', // App ID
      channelUrl : '..../channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // connected
        apiCall();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
      login();
    } else {
        // not_logged_in
      login();
    }
    });

  };

   function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
          apiCall();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, { scope: 'email' });
  }

  function apiCall() {

    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        var first_name = response.first_name;
        var last_name = response.last_name;
        var fb_id = response.id;
        var email = response.email;


    });
  }

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
 });
```

html :

What should I change or add to prevent the popup blocker issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the user to the login page rather than popping up the authorisation dialog.

You could also make the login be triggered by a user action - if the user clicks on a link which triggers the popup it will be much less likely to be blocked (rather than triggering the login programmatically).